# Reactjs a tag href param (timestamp) changes after clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple `<a>` tag with a href containing current timestamp `new Date().getTime()` as a queryParam (token). When hovering over the a tag on the page you can see the url that is produced:[image: with 1496149410652 being the the timestamp]

However when actually clicking the element, the timestamp is recalculated and this is the call that is happening: `http://localhost:8080/api/exports?token=1496149559627`.

I use the same token/timestamp in the `onClick` handler of the `<a>` tag and the timestamp send there is the same as the one that was calculated when the component was rendered. 
Why is it different in the href attribute and can I change it ?

code:

```
const downloadUrl = `http://localhost:8080/api/exports`;
const token = new Date().getTime();
return (
        <a href={downloadUrl + `?token=${token}`}
           onClick={() => handleOnClick(token)}>
               <span>click here</span> 
        </a>
)
```